# (Python) Did not understand 'RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars'

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a statement in the loop that generates a matrix

```
zij_mat[i][j]=(p_ij1-p_ij)/math.sqrt(((p_ij*(1-p_ij))/Ni_series[grades[i]]) + ((p_ij1*(1-p_ij1))/Ni_series[grades[i]]) + ((2*p_ij*p_ij1)/Ni_series[grades[i]]))
```

It gives runtime warning as 'invalid value encountered in double_scalars' and places **nan** values in some positions of the matrix.

it might be divide by zero condition I thought

then I tried this code

```
try:
    zij_mat[i][j]=(p_ij1-p_ij)/math.sqrt(((p_ij*(1-p_ij))/Ni_series[grades[i]]) + ((p_ij1*(1-p_ij1))/Ni_series[grades[i]]) + ((2*p_ij*p_ij1)/Ni_series[grades[i]]))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    zij_mat[i][j]=0
    continue
```

again it encounters the same warning.

Can anyone please help me to get rid of this problem?

Thank you

Comment: The warning is from `numpy`, so trying to catch the `ZeroDivisionError` directly won't pick it up.  Try setting `numpy.seterr('raise')` so that you can see more information to debug.  Alternatively/additionally, if you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can help debug.

Comment: thanks, after setting numpy.seterr(raise) it encounters 'FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in double_scalars'. how to solve this problem now?

Comment: Now try changing `ZeroDivisionError` to `FloatingPointError` in the `try`/`except` statement.

Comment: Worked, Hurrayyy, uuuuuu, Thank you soo much Chris

Comment: No problem Mohd!